# SEM or path analysis using AMOS, issues with sample size and model complexity

Tags: sample-size, structural-equation-modeling, path-model, amos

I am new to SEM / AMOS and as such I have done a lot of reading around my problem but find I am getting lost, any help would be appreciated and I am sorry if this sounds rather basic;

1. I have a model that looks at a number of factors (distal, indirect factors) which include 5 factors of personality and a couple of 'other factors' shown to be related to 2 distinct accident behaviours (outcome variables, DVs etc)
2. There are 2 mediating factors between the distal and outcome variables
3. the mediating variables and outcome variables are bi directional so I have an non recursive model.
4. I have relatively small sample of 200 for the purposes of SEM depending on the perspective you take on this.

I understand the principles of SEM and here lies my problem, to include a measurement model with observed variables that underlie these factors is not possible (the 5 individual factors are measured by a 120 item questionnaire), this puts unrealistic demands on sample size and simply drawing a model like this seems impossible.

I was looking at the use of Path Analysis which I understand is a form of SEM. Here I treat the factors as observed variables so lose the ability to account for measurement error. There are also issues with testing a non-recursive model here.

I should say that I conducted a series of multiple regressions to establsh the best predictors of the 2 mediating and 2 outcome variables to form I suppose a 'conceptual' model that I would like to test and test the mediating variables. I hope this makes sense to someone..The more I read, the more I am getting a little overwhelmed and was hoping someone could offer some guidance or comments?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Sarah, welcome to the site. You can also ask this question on SEMNET mailing list.

Comment: many thanks for your kind response. May I just clarify some of your points so I understand fully what you are recommending? The 5 personality factors ('O' 'C' 'E' 'A' & 'N') are measured by 6 sub scores. The total questionnaire is 120 items to measure all the personality factors and is on a likert scale (1-7) and each sub scores is summed together to get one score for each factor. Another of my latent variables is a cognitive abilities score (CFQ). 1 summed score (no sub items) from 25 items. I have another factor to measure something called safety climate, with 5 sub. So drawing a measurement

Comment: Re-post this as an update for your original question, and delete this is an answer. This is not a forum when you can just keep stringing questions at the bottom, and makes the question extremely confusing.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't know.

Answer (score 2):

Wow. 120 items is a lot. Are they yes/no (0/1)? Do you just use a simple sum?

You could try approaching this with fixed reliabilities of your factors. Compute your scores and store them as say `f1score` through `f5score`. In AMOS, specify latent variables as circles with `f1` through `f5` in them, and connect them to the rest of the model. Now, connect each of the latent with the corresponding scores, `f1 -> f1score`, etc. Set the path coefficient to be 1; set the measurement error for `f1score` to be 1 minus the (generalized) reliability of the score. If you don't have the latter from previous research on the psychometric characteristic of your scales, you would have to compute that, too; see 
[Raykov's work](http://www.citeulike.org/user/ctacmo/article/11142737) on the topic.

Be aware that regression when regressors are measured with error [attenuates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Errors-in-variables_models) coefficients (biases them towards zero). See also [Skrondal and Laake 2001](http://www.citeulike.org/user/ctacmo/article/2663962).